# Hide Crystal Reports specific details

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have 4 values in Crystal Reports.

- COA  Balance
- DR Amount
- Credit Amount
- Total Amount

The formula is COA Balance-DR Balance or CR Balance = Total Amount

Now I want to hide COA Balance from user who check the report from vb.net application. Is it possible to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on TextObject of COA Balance and add if condition in Suppress section.[image]